# In App Purchase Problem - Where Am I Going Wrong ? iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, xcode4, in-app-purchase

I am trying to test my in app purchase (in sandbox) and have the following problem :

- The app retrieves the available products successfully and displays them in a table.
- The user clicks on "Buy"
- The user is asked to enter user name and password (this is my test user).
- A confirmation comes back saying on screen that the transcation was succesful.

The problem is that the content is then not downloaded and that the following method doesn't seem to be called :

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether you added transaction observer

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]addTransactionObserver:mObserverObject];
```

Where mObserverObject is the object of class where you have implemented updatedTransactions method.

Comment: Hi Chandan. Thanks for your help. I have put this code in the app delegate in didfinishlaunching with options - is this the problem ?// At top of file
#import "InAppHelper.h"
 
// In application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:[InAppHelper sharedHelper]];

Comment: I dont think so... Are you sure that [InAppHelper sharedHelper] is returning proper object.

Comment: I think so. It's a singleton method. static InAppHelper * _sharedHelper;
 
+ (InAppHelper *) sharedHelper {
 
    if (_sharedHelper != nil) {
        return _sharedHelper;
    }
    _sharedHelper = [[InAppHelper alloc] init];
    return _sharedHelper;

Comment: I think this is a problem with my viewdidloadwithoptions - I'm going to check later - thank you.

Comment: Chandan. All sorted - thank you for your help - it's people like you that make this a great site. The problem was my viewdidloadwithoptions in app delegate was being skipped as the files owned was linked incorrectly in my main window nib.